# Array stored in the sqlite3

Tags: javascript, arrays, sqlite

I am new to Sqlite3, coming to the point directly I have an javascript array, inside that I have another array eg.,

```
var partha = [
                 [
                  'partha1','partha2',[
                                       'inside_array_partha1',
                                       'inside_array_partha2',
                                       'inside_array_partha1'
                                      ]
                 ],
                 [
                  'sarathy1','sarathy2',[
                                       'inside_array_sarathy1',
                                       'inside_array_sarathy2',
                                       'inside_array_sarathy1'
                                      ]
                 ]
             ]
```

I am interested in storing these values in the sqlite3 database, I have no idea now to create an table for it for faster retrieval.

I tried like of converting the js array into string by `JSON.stringfy()` method but when querying back Am not able to get properly as well the fetching time is also high.

Is there any other way to create an effective table for storing this values in the DB with fast retrieval way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A table for each array dimension, many-many relationships on the inner dimensions. It won't ever be faster than that array unless that array gets too big to be caching.

Comment: Is it always 2 entries in the outer array followed by one array with three entries in an inner array?